# how to restore database from other server - sql

Tags: sql-server, security, restore

I have backup database from server A. Then I want to restore it in server B.
I have manage to restore it, but I cannot connect to it when running my VB program. I already change the configuration file, but still doesn't work.

I guess that I need to change something related with the permission, but I dont know what should I change. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What database software? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PG, etc....?

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault

Comment: @Verbeia or possibly on DBA

Comment: @JakeFeasel yes but SF is in the list when one votes to close ;-)

Comment: try to create new login.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of more information, I'll guess SQL Server.

- SQL Server uses logins to connect at the Instance (server) level
- A login maps to a user in a databases

You can see this in SSMS in the Security nodes on Object Explorer.

I suspect you have "orphaned" users. That is, the users in your restored database no longer have an associated login to map to. This need recreated (Windows logins) or remapped (SQL logins)

The MSDN article [Troubleshooting Orphaned Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx) has checks, fixes and more details. I'd simply copy/paste or re-hash this so I recommend you look at this.

Comment: yes, im using MS SQL Server 2005.

for the parent server, i have created a user which is user A. 
for the database, i give permission for user A to access the database.

am i doing the right thing?

Comment: @Humaira Laila: if you have created a SQL login called "userA" on the new server then you need to map it as per the link I gave.

Comment: i guess it is because, the setting for database user:dbo is from server A. since i overwrite the bakup file, it had restore all the user too. that is why it the database cannot be access. but i try to modified the login setting for dbo, but it cannot be modified.any idea?

Comment: Don't change dbo, please read the link and run ALTER USER UserA ...

Comment: OK i have restore again the database. so now everything is set the initial.For my database, i open user(dbo) properties. i realize that the login name is empty,so as you said, this is what we called orphaned users. then i try to change the login name, so i run this query : 
USE <databasename>;
exec sp_changedbowner <loginuser>;

then i change the config file:
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AMR.My.MySettings.AMRConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=AMR;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

still doesn't work

Comment: actually i took the database from ms sql express server..
then i restore in ms sql 2005 server..when i look at ms sql surface configuration, it stated that, by default, ms sql express edition allow local client connection only..does it the reason why i cannot access the database?